# HTML with Python CGI (if else)

Tags: python, if-statement, cgi

I am doing simple if else in my code but when I put if else, when I run it. It gives me Internal Server Errors. But when I remove if else in the code its working, But I cannot get the correct display, like "The number is EVEN" or "The number is ODD". Its only gives "The number is "

```
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")

import cgi, cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 


# Get data from fields
#input_number = form.getvalue('input_number')
input_number=input()
if  input_number % 2==0 : 
    answer = "EVEN"
else:
 answer = "ODD"
   
print('<html>')
print('<head>')
print('<title> The Results of Comparing Odd and Even Numbers</title>')
print('</head>')
print('<body>')
print('<table>')
print('<tr>')
print('<td> The number is   </td>')
 print('<td>    ' + answer + '</td>') 
print('</tr>')
print('</table>')
print('</body>')
print('</html>')
```

Comment: Please provide us with the full `error message` :) Also you seem to have syntax errors in your code.

Comment: When I try to run my code it always appear 500 Internal Server Error. Since I'm using Python v3...it quite different to what I saw in tutorials and it also gives me a 500 Internal Server Error. Thank You in Advance. I hope you understand what I am trying to say. Sorry, Its my first time to code using python cgi.

Comment: Side note: you've got TD (table-data-cell) and TR (table-row) swapped

Comment: Please provide the full error message. At what line does this occur?

Comment: @JakubSzlaur I couldn't find what line but is always appear this in the website......Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at ----------- to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Answer (score 0):

finally I got to understand how to use xampp and I finally got to know what is the error then  I change my code like here

```
 `
input_number = form.getvalue('input_number')
if  int(input_number) % 2==0 : 
    answer = "EVEN"
else:
 answer = "ODD"`
```